# 3 deep jquery ul list - want only 2nd ul to show when 1st clicked

Tags: jquery

I have a three deep ul list.  When the top ul is clicked I only want the 2nd ul to show.  Then when the second ul is clicked the third should show.  What happens now is when the first ul is clicked, all ul's underneath show.  How can I get this to work properly?

Code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  jQuery('.list-year').addClass('list-year-left');
  jQuery('.list-year').on('click',(function() { 
    jQuery('.list-year').toggleClass('list-year-down');
    jQuery('.list-month').toggle();  
  }));

});
```

I have a js fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/7xbjr/4/  Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Shouldn't there be some use of `$(this)` in the handlers? Otherwise you'll toggle all years and months, not just the ones under the UL you click. Your fiddle only has one year and month, so it doesn't run into this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The class of `<li>` is `list-post`, but you have defined it as `list-posts` which is not match.

```
.list-posts {
  display: none;
}
```

Should become

```
.list-post {
  display: none;
}
```

Moreover, the click event should bind to the `<li>` element instead of `<ul>`. Please note that if you are binding a click event in children element, it is recommended to stop the event propagation, otherwise the click event will propagate to parent's click event.

Here is the JavaScript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.list-year').addClass('list-year-left');
    jQuery('.list-year > li').on('click', function() { 
        jQuery('.list-year').toggleClass('list-year-down');
        jQuery('.list-month').toggle(); 
    });

    jQuery('.list-month > li').on('click',function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation(); // add this for avoiding click event propagate to parent 
        jQuery('.list-post').toggle(); 
    });
});
```

jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/BMc43/2/

Answer (score 0):

Your code could be more tidy, but here you go http://jsfiddle.net/BMc43/3/:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.list-year').addClass('list-year-left');
    jQuery('.list-year').on('click',(function() { 
        jQuery('.list-year').toggleClass('list-year-down');
        jQuery('.list-month').toggle(); 
    }));

    jQuery('.list-month').on('click',(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        jQuery('.list-post').toggle(); 
    }));
});
```

And of course you have to change `.list-posts` to `.list-post` in CSS as Derek said.

Answer (score 0):

The following things were wrong:

- You had a class list-post and you referred to it as list-posts.
- your click events fired whenever you clicked a child node, triggering the toggle again and closing your menu.
- you needed to add an additional click event for the third level menu

http://jsfiddle.net/7xbjr/5/
here is an updated fiddle which works

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
 jQuery('.list-year').addClass('list-year-left');
  jQuery('.list-year > li').on('click',function() { 
    jQuery('.list-year').toggleClass('list-year-down');
    jQuery('.list-month').toggle();  
  });
  jQuery('.list-month > li').on('click',function() { 
    jQuery('.list-post').toggle();  
  });
});
```

Comment: it is custom to upvote and select a correct answer once you find one that works. =)